Particle emissions on animated objects are not emitted uniformly when animated
I added particle emission to the back of the sword, if I animate a sword swing/spin slowly, it works correctly, but if I animate a little fast, the particles appear as seen in the screenshot.
Is there a way to make the particles flow evenly? As you can see in the screenshot, it's like they emit and stop emitting intermittently. I want the trail to be fluid and uniform, without emission cuts.
Thanks in advance.
EDIT:
Here the blend file:



Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

Sure friend, here is the file, I tried to remove all unnecessary because I don't know what the size limit per file is:
https://blend-exchange.com/b/skqv3bZn/

Issue
The issue is that your particle system doesn't have any subframe information to work with.
This means that the particle system can only update each frame. However, if we have curves or keyframes, Blender can look at what's happening in-between and make subframe calculations and calculate "continuously" along that curve.
However, your sword doesn't have any keyframes, it's parented to an armature.
Solution
We need to bake the animation to the sword.
With the sword selected. Click Object > Animation > Bake Action

We want to bake the animation (Visual Keying) via the location and rotation. We also want to clear the parent so it's acting independently.

Now we get particles at subframes


Omg, I would have never been able to find the problem without your help, thanks a lot friend! Does this only happen because the sword is fused to an armor? If I do the animation with the sword separated from the armature this shouldn't happen, right? (this model can use a sword fused to the armature or independent, but I chose the one that is fused to the hands/armature)

This happens because the particle system uses the animation info from it's parent object. So yes, this happens because its fused to the armor. Personally, I would keep the setup you have. And when you are ready to render: Duplicate the sword -> particle system -> bake animation -> hide emitter in the particle system. That way it's not too difficult to adjust armature animation if you need to.

Thanks again, this works, I think it's the only way to get it working. But I've been trying other methods for hours, such as selecting armature sword + shift + armature model + Pose Mode + Auto Keying, but the sword keyframe is not created in the timeline, not even inserting it with "i". Sorry, I know the thread is closed and you've already solved the problem, but do you think there's a way to get the sword keyframe registered in the timeline while I'm animating the armature model? (without leaving Pose Mode) I guess not, but I wanted to try to be 100% sure, anyway your method works perfectly!
